# How to obtain an errored.tfstate file from Terraform Cloud?

Tags: diagnostics, terraform-cloud

I have a Terraform deployment that gets applied through Circle CI. It seems that when Circle applies it, it errors out, but when I apply manually I'm unable to reproduce the behavior.

The error I get is:

```
Error: Failed to persist state to backend

The error shown above has prevented Terraform from writing the updated state to the configured backend. To allow for recovery, the state has been written to the file "errored.tfstate" in the current working directory.

Running "terraform apply" again at this point will create a forked state, making it harder to recover.

To retry writing this state, use the following command:
    terraform state push errored.tfstate
```

If I could see this `errored.tfstate` file, it would probably help me diagnose the issue. However, can I obtain it from Terraform itself?

Note: I am not asking here why the error is happening - I intend to make a separate question about that. I am only asking where to obtain the `errored.tfstate`.